# How to order ag-Grid and AdapTable menu items

Tags: datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are using ag-Grid (React version) integrated with AdapTable.

Is there a way to sort or order the context menu so that our custom menu items appear first, followed by the AdapTable ones and then ag-Grid ones after that?

I can see how to choose which menu items should appear and how to stop some from displaying but not how to order the sections.

Answer (score 1):

Do it via the `contextMenuOrder` property in User Interface Options

You will want

```
adaptableOptions.userInterfaceOptions = {
  columnMenuOrder: ['user', 'adaptable', 'vendor']
};
```

See: https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/adaptable-options/user-interface-options

General menu documentation at:  https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/user-interface/column-menu#items-order